# Async Jasmine test doesn't invoke beforeEach() before operating

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, testing, jasmine

I'm trying to code a test to my client-server modules. I need to run the server before the client is sending its requests, so I'm trying to use `beforeEach`, but the test fails before the server even started running.

My test:

```
'use strict';
const cp    = require('child_process');
const ip    = require('my-local-ip');
const utils = require('../util/utils');

describe('Server and client connectivity:', () => {

    let originalTimeout;
    let server;

    beforeEach(function() {
        server = cp.fork('Server/Server');
        originalTimeout = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;
    });

    it('should transfer index.html file to client', (done) => {
        const client = cp.fork('Client/request', ['-t', ip(), '-p', 3300]);
        expect(utils.isFileExistsInDirectory('Client/', 'index.html')).toBe(true);
        done();
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = originalTimeout;
    });

});
```

When I'm running manually first the server, and then the client with these commands, it works perfectly.
In the test sometimes the client request is sent **before** the server is listening. 
How could it happen?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the current implementation, you're forking the server process but *not* waiting until the server actually launches.

To fix this we need to set up some inter-process communication.
In case of using `fork`, that's easy to do by using `.send` and `.on` because:

> The returned ChildProcess will have an additional communication
>   channel built-in that allows messages to be passed back and forth
>   between the parent and child...

as per [the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options).

Please see the example `server.js`:

```js
// A simple server
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.json({message: 'ok'}));

app.listen(8080, () => {
 // This function exists only if this is a child process
 if (process.send) {
  // Telling the parent that the server is launched
  process.send('launched');
 }

 console.log('Server started');
});
```

And `spec.js`:

```js
const child_process = require('child_process');
const request = require('request');
const assert = require('assert');

describe('Connectivity with forked server', () => {
 let server;

 beforeAll(done => {
  server = child_process.fork('server.js');

  // Wait for the message from a child server before running any tests
  server.on('message', data => {
   if (data === 'launched') {
    console.log('Before block executed');
    done();
   }
  });
 });

 // Killing the server after all the tests
 afterAll(() => server.kill('SIGTERM'));

 it('should be able to interact with server', done => {
  request({url: 'http://localhost:8080', json: true}, (err, resp, body) => {
   if (err) {
    return done(err);
   }

   assert.equal(body.message, 'ok');

   console.log('test executed');
   done();
  });
 });
});
```

I've used `beforeAll` and `afterAll` instead of `beforeEach` but you can switch back to `beforeEach` if needed.

Also, I've set up some logic to shut down the process after the tests are executed.